# ReactiveCocoa, combine two signals on button enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm using MVVM architecture and I have two signals:

```
RACSignal *internetEnabledSignal = RACObserve(self.regWizardVehicleViewModel, internetConnectionEnabled);
RACSignal *executingRegistrationSignal = RACObserve(self.regWizardVehicleViewModel, isExecuting);
```

I need to combine and bind signals on button enabled property. Button needs to be disabled if there is not any connection OR when some method is executing. I was searching and searching for solution but I don't know how to combine signals with OR. Is there any way to do that? Next question is: I'm using MBProgressHUD. I want to show that HUD while executing my async method in my Model. MBProgressHUD has show and hide methods, can't bind it to a property like button enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding you, then the functionality should be easily achievable with `combineLatest:reduce:`, like so:

```
RACSignal * enabledSignal = 
[RACSignal combineLatest:@[internetEnabledSignal, executingRegistrationSignal] 
reduce:^id(NSNumber * internetEnabled, NSNumber * isExecuting) {
    return @(internetEnabled.boolValue && !isExecuting.boolValue);
}].distinctUntilChanged;

RAC(self.button, enabled) = enabledSignal;
```

`combineLatest:reduce:` won't send any next events until all signals have fired at least once, so please keep that in mind.

**Edit**: Please see Michał's answer for a much cooler solution via convenience methods.

As for your other question, I'm not very familiar with MBProgressHUD but this should do the trick:

```
[self.hud rac_liftSelector:@selector(show:) withSignalsFromArray:@[
    [enabledSignal ignore:@NO]
]];
[self.hud rac_liftSelector:@selector(hide:) withSignalsFromArray:@[
    [[enabledSignal ignore:@YES] mapReplace:@YES]
]];
```

This is a bit of a cheat, we're leveraging RAC's eager subscription to these signals to fire side effects, but if you're a pragmatist and not a pedantic idealist like me, you probably don't mind.

What's happening with this code is that we're asking RAC to perform the given selector after every one of the signals in the array we supplied fires, so it's a lot like `combineLatest:`. We're using `mapReplace:` because it'll use that signal as the `(BOOL)animated` argument (this is another reason why it's a cheat).

Answer (score 9):

There is a convenience method, [`-and`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.5/Classes/RACSignal.html#//api/name/and) which makes working with "boolean" value signals easier:

> Returns a signal that applies AND to each NSNumber in the tuple.

To get a tuple with `NSNumbers`, use `combineLatestWith:` like this:

```
   RAC(self.button, enabled) =[[[executingRegistrationSignal not] 
        combineLatestWith:internetEnabledSignal]
         and];
```

Comment: Great simple usage. I will mark this answer as useful, but previous answer has answer on my other question so that answer is complete. Thank you very much :)